# How can a HTTP request be instantiated with a different host?

Tags: http, http-headers, fiddler, http-request

Strange one here folks.

I'm studiying a web application's inner workings using Fiddler and have become a bit stumped.  I'm requesting `/account` via the browser and Fiddler shows in the "Host" column `website.local` as expected since this is the URL the browser is pointing at.

Immediately after this a second request is made, however this time the host is `services.website.com`.  I also cannot find any script in `/account` that makes this request.

So how can the Host change?  Where is the response being sent to?  Where can this be getting called from?

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect that the server is sending a redirect to `services.website.com`: Fiddler isn't showing any redirects?

Comment: Nope all responses are 200 OK

Comment: Quite odd. Perhaps there is an unqualified domain somewhere (`services.website`, perhaps) and IE is qualifying it with a `.com`? If you are legitimately not receiving any 300 responses and there isn't a `document.location` call in any of the javascript that would seem like the only other option I can think of.

Comment: It's quite likely that this is something in the content. You should consider reading this: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/howto.asp#initiator

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what really is in the first response that you receive. When you see a second request in Fiddler, does the page change too (in the browser)?

It will help a great deal if you could share the part of the Fiddler trace.